# rspec Test Result Capybara::ElementNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I've been asked to help out on a Rails app.  I'm going through some failing rpsec tests and getting them to pass.  I've got one on which I'm banging my head against a wall.  We are using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 2.0  Note: I'm totally a nube on rspec.

I have a form with an id of vet-as-faculty.  The test is looking for this and not finding it.  I get the error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "form#vet-as-faculty
```

I get a similar error on other form elements in the test also, but the test is failing on or at this point.

I know this "usually" means the markup on the form is not correct or something in the test is misspelled (I've found a few of those).  But this one I just cannot get.  I've Googled on this error and found a bit of stuff, but nothing that seems to help me on this one.  I'm hoping you gurus out there will see something simple for me.

Form/view (in part):

```
 <%= form_for @profile, :url => { :action => :vet_as_faculty }, :html => { :id => "vet-as-faculty" } do |f| %>
  <fieldset class="row1"><legend>Vet Me As Faculty</legend>
    <div class="form-pair" id="faculty-url">
    <div class="form-item">
      <label>Faculty URL</label>
    </div>
  <fieldset class="row2">
    <div class="form-submit" id="save-faculty">
      <%= f.submit "Send for Review" %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

View source shows this as:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/research/chr/casestudies/profile/vet_as_faculty" class="edit_user" id="vet-as-faculty" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="FZtjli8HaGD3koUvSFAYR2Gy+waL8KDWflMNUo4tXXw=" /></div>
  <fieldset class="row1"><legend>Vet Me As Faculty</legend>
    <div class="form-pair" id="faculty-url">
      <div class="form-item">
        <label>Faculty URL</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-value">
        <input id="user_faculty_url" name="user[faculty_url]" size="30" type="text" />
      </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="row2">
    <div class="form-submit" id="save-faculty">
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Send for Review" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
...
```

So, I see the for id as 'id="vet-as-faculty"'. but, the test does not see this.

The Test Code:

```
context "within the faculty vetting block" do
    it "has the necessary form fields" do
      within "form#vet-as-faculty" do 
        expect(page).to have_css("input#user_faculty_url")
        expect(page).to have_css("input#save-faculty")
      end
    end
 end
```

The error output for this one test:

```
3) Edit Profile View within the faculty vetting block has the necessary form fields
   Failure/Error: within "form#vet-as-faculty" do
   Capybara::ElementNotFound:
     Unable to find css "form#vet-as-faculty"
   # ./spec/features/edit_profile_view_spec.rb:48:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've tried to add more drill down type css in the test

```
within "#page #content form#vet-as-faculty" do
```

The form is inside div#content and content is inside div#page.  This does not help either.

Any thoughts?  Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Are you sure you are on the page you think you are on? There is no visit method call in your test you shared with us.

Comment: Have you tried foregoing the `within` block? You can state your expectations within the `it` block (so that the spec scans the entire page) and see if that helps. Capybara feature specs can be pretty fickle. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Maybe the code does is not seeing the view page.  As noted I'm totally new to rspec.  I see a block with 'background do'.  In it there is a line: visit edit_profile_path(@user).  I do not know if that is what you are referring to.  I'll get with the programmer who coded this and ask him.  Thanks

Comment: aceofbassgreg: Yes, I tried commenting out the within block.  The same error shows for the faculty-url id and the submit button id.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is that you haven't actually navigated to the page where your form is

```
before { visit new_my_model_path }
```

As a more general piece of advice. Avoid writing tests that just assert markup/css. Focus on the behavior you need this form to accomplish instead and your tests will be a lot more valuable.